# How to sort a list by last character of string

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I am trying to write a program that orders a list of strings based on the last character in the item.

`["Tiger 6", "Shark 4", "Cyborg 8"]` are how my list is imported, but I need to put them in numerical order based on the numbers at the end.

Comment: are the numbers always single digits?

Comment: In this instance, yes.

Answer (score 21):

> I am trying to write a program that orders a list of strings based on the last character in the item.

```
>>> s = ["Tiger 6", "Shark 4", "Cyborg 8"]
>>> sorted(s, key=lambda x: int(x[-1]))
['Shark 4', 'Tiger 6', 'Cyborg 8']
```

Try this if there are more num of digits at the last.

```
>>> import re
>>> sorted(s, key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+$',x).group()))
['Shark 4', 'Tiger 6', 'Cyborg 8']
```

`re.search(r'\d+$',x).group()` helps to fetch the number present at the last irrespective of preceding space.

Comment: Why use a lambda for the key instead of a *function*.

Comment: lambda is used to create anonymous function.

Answer (score 5):

```
def last_letter(word):
    return word[::-1]

mylst = ["Tiger 6", "Shark 4", "Cyborg 8"]
sorted(mylst, key=last_letter)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
nums = ["Tiger 6", "Shark 4", "Cyborg 8"]
slist=sorted(nums,key = lambda x:x[-1])
```

1. here **nums** is an list
2. in **slist** it takes list of arguments from the list **nums**
3. here lambda function takes argument from list and return it's last value(e.g. 
   if it a first argument from **nums** (i.e.**''Tiger 6''**) and it returns 
   **6**.
4. **sorted** function return a list based on **lambda function**.

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are not single digits, you can try -

```
>>> l = ["Tiger 6", "Shark 4", "Cyborg 8", "Temporary 12"]
>>> l.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.rsplit(' ',1)[1]))
>>> l
['Shark 4', 'Tiger 6', 'Cyborg 8', 'Temporary 12']
```

`str.rsplit(s, n)` function starts splitting the string at the end towards start of the string and stops after n splits. In the above case, it only splits the string once, at a space.