# Sort a zipped list (string,instances of 'Line2D') by the last character of the string

Tags: sorting, matplotlib, zip, legend

I would like to sort the list of labels, handles that I obtained from the legend in Matplotlib after the last character of the string in labels.

So far I tried to combine this thread:
[How is order of items in matplotlib legend determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263807/how-is-order-of-items-in-matplotlib-legend-determined)
with this thread:
[How to sort a list by last character of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306951/how-to-sort-a-list-by-last-character-of-string)
which unfortunately did not work. Here is my Code:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

handles, labels = zip(*sorted(zip(labels, handles), key = lambda t:[0]))

leg = ax.legend(handles, labels,loc='best', ncol=2, shadow=True, fancybox=True)
```

Which basically does nothing.

Here are the printouts:

```
print(handles)
print(labels)

[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fd6182ddcd0>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fd6182ddb50>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fd6448ddc10>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fd6448ddf50>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fd6609cb790>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fd6609cb190>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fd660ac5f10>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fd660ac5e90>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fd619404d10>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fd645fcb9d0>]
['Demo_4 maximum', 'Demo_4 mean', 'Demo_5 maximum', 'Demo_5 mean', 'Demo_6 maximum', 'Demo_6 mean', 'Demo_7 maximum', 'Demo_7 mean', 'Demo_8 maximum', 'Demo_8 mean']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. There are a few corrections to be made to the line

```
handles, labels = zip(*sorted(zip(labels, handles), key = lambda t:[0]))
```

1. If you expect to receive `handles, labels,`, then you have to zip in the same order: `zip(handles, labels)`
2. The key to sort by the first list would be `lambda t: t[0]` (notice the t). But because we now have handles first, and labels second, to sort by labels, it would be `lambda t: t[1]` (1 is the second list, in this case, labels)
3. But you do not want to sort by labels, but by the last character of labels. You get the last character of a string `s` by `s[-1]`. So, the key should be `lambda t: t[1][-1]` (the [1] because labels is in the second position; the [-1] because you want the last character of each label).

So:

```
handles, labels = zip(*sorted(zip(handles, labels), key = lambda t: t[1][-1]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)